# Sidemenu On Top

Tags: android, codenameone

I am using the SideMenuOnTop feature in my app but everything I have tried does not work. I have added the Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(true) in my init() method but still does not work. I even called the static method directly rather than using the class reference (form.getToolbar().setOnTopSideMenu(true) ) still does not work. I created a new project and used the feature and it works. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work? Screenshots?

Comment: thats the screenshot. After adding the required code to my init() method, I expected the sidemenu to open on top

Comment: Are you using the `Toolbar` API? Did you customize any theme constants? Notice you should only use the toolbar side menu API and shouldn't set theme constants especially not the menu behavior stuff